# How to get rid of class "fluid-width-video-wrapper" from video embed wordpress

Tags: wordpress, embed

I am getting a class "fluid-width-video-wrapper" with padding"59%".

can anybody let me know, how can i get rid of this class.
I don't found this class in files also.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I want just to extend a bit @FEMP's answer.

Indeed, the wrapper added by the FitVids.js plugin.

You can simply add the `fitvidsignore` class to your `<iframe>` to ignore all effects of the plugin. It will be useful if you still need this script on some other page...

Comment: I see that the question is quite old, but believe the answer would help some other people (like me) which could experience this problem in future

Comment: A specific scenario where this helped (hoping to aid future searchers): I am using WordPress with the Beaver Builder theme and plugin, and was using a Vimeo "responsive" embed. Beaver Builder includes the FitVids.js plugin, so there were two competing "responsive" inline styles that resulted (in this case) in a lot of extra space above the video. Using `fitvidsignore` on the iframe worked, but the better solution in this case was to use Vimeo's basic, non-responsive embed code and let FitVids.js do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

Check your code for FitVids.js it's a plugin for fitting video on the page, check it here:
https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js

Comment: Yep. For future people... maybe you don't know you even have a plugin there... but check the appearance > FitVids - and set a specific class instead of all `iframe` elements. : )

Answer (score 1):

It probably gets added later when the page is loaded according to settings/other classes on the page. You could always remove it after the page is loaded: (replace #ID).

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#ID").removeClass("fluid-width-video-wrapper") 
});
```

EDIT: Assuming you loaded jQuery on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was experiencing a massive gap because padding-top was being applied to this div. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with css

```
.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    display: contents !important;
}
```

This helps to remove that extra spacing. Make sure you call this with parent class.